# function template with non-type parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am very new on C++ templated code. could you please educate me on the following questions:
If I want to use function template (that only has non-type parameters) to define member function for a class, do I also need to define template for that class too. or in other word, does C++ allow user to define member function template (that has only non-type parameters) within untemplated class. for instance:

```
class foo{

template <int vecsize>
void bar(std::array<int, vecsize> vec);
};
```

thank you.

Comment: It is perfectly OK to have a template member in a non-template class. The kind of template parameters doesn't matter. Having said that, std::vector doesn't have a size parameter.

Comment: Did you mean perhaps `std::array<int, vecsize>`?

Comment: thank you guys for answer my question.  I have updated my post so that it would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, member function templates don't require the parent structure to be templatized (but it could be a template of course).

It seems you want a `std::array` instead of `std::vector` (as n.m. mentioned there is no size parameter for std::vector).

And you're missing a semicolon at the end of the class definition

Comment: sorry about being sloppy on the syntax. Yes you are right, I should be using;  & std::array.